# div alignment in css on Chrome, FF and IE 7 on Windows XP

Tags: css, html, alignment

i have problems with the alignment of divs.

My layout consists of one div view_central which contains three other divs namely `view_central_top`, `view_central_left` and `view_central_right`. Chrome and FF render the wanted result: a top div with a bannner, the navigaiton to the left and the content to the right.

IE 7 offsets the content div `view_central_right` 10 px to high thus covering part of the banner div `view_central_top`.

The css code looks like this:

```
.view_central
{
    position: relative;
    width: 827px;
    height: 100%;
}

.view_central_top
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0xp;
    left: 0px;
    height: 118px;
    width: 828px;
}

.image_borderless
{
    border: 0px none;
}

.view_central_left
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 118px;
    width: 187px;
    height: 683px;
    background: #C7D2EB;
    font-size: 11px;
}

.view_central_right
{
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    top: 118px;
    width: 640px;
    height: 683px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Can anyone help me out. Thanks.

Comment: Could you also post the HTML and perhaps a link to a test case?

Comment: Is it necessary to have all the positioning in there? Can we see the markup?

Comment: Not sure if it is related to your problem but the top property for .view_central_top has units 'xp' instead of 'px'

Comment: Yeah, 0 should not have a unit to begin with.

Comment: Thanks. Turners are hard to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first thought -- browser dependent padding or margins.  A CSS reset (at least for `div` elements) might be worth trying.

Comment: Thanks. You made my day. 

After resetting the css (for e.g. code on that see  http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) chrome, ff and ie 7 showed the same behaviour offsetting the div view_central_right 10 px to0 high. With margin-top i can now reposition the div view_central_right to the needed position in all three browsers:

.view_central_right
{
 position: relative;
 left: 188px;
 top: 118px;
 width: 640px;
 height: 683px;
 background: #FFFFFF;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

Thanks again.